# Is resource usage increased when assigning object propery to local variable?

Tags: javascript

I know that Javascript is (mostly and relatively) "assigned by reference language", but I also know this:

```
var object1 = {Lorem:"ipsum"};
var object2 = object1;

object1='some string';
console.log(object2)// {Lorem:"ipsum"}
```

My goal is to determinate if (potentially) resource consuming property of global object, used in local variable declaration, hits memory.

*File1.js*

```
window.AppResources={};
// ...
// ... AppResources being filled with properties, 
// ... strings, objects, functions...
AppResources.heavyFunction = function(){
    //some complex fn
};
AppResources.heavyString = '';//some 500KB string...
// ...
```

*File2.js*

```
;(function(win,doc, AppR){

    var localFunction = AppR.heavyFunction,
    var localString = AppR.heavyString;
    // ...
})(window, document, AppResources);
```

I'm concerned if this doubles the values.
Do I hit the memory with this assignments - should I use object property instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is no.

Assigning a heavy string to a variable to another won't duplicate content, and therefore won't hit memory. Assigning it to a variable or to an object property have the same effect

```js
var randomString = (function() { // a 1Mb string (16 bits per char)
  var result = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < 50000; ++i) {
    result += "aaaaaaaaaa";
  }
  return result;
}());


var obj = {};
var counter = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  var a = randomString; // local variable assignation in a function
  obj[counter++] = a ;
  console.log(Object.keys(obj).length);
}, 500);
```

And  here is a memory profile over time:

[image]

In which you see the initial allocation, and no other happening, despite the frequent assignations

Comment: even setting completely new object properties of `obj` ( obj.1='1mb string', obj.2='1mb string' ... ) doesn't increase memory? I would never guess that.

Comment: In that case you manually allocate, you don't assign an existing string to something. in fact, in my example, memory increases due to the amount of keys in obj, but it's about a few bytes.